# Use two datasources with jdbc template

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

So,
I've worked on a spring boot project and now I am working on the database. I thought that it would be best to set two users for the database:

one that has access to the user table for `login/register/information` update and another for accessing the other tables.

My idea was to create two separate beans for two DataSources each with a separate user and when a user wants to log in, the controller would change the JDBCtemplate DataSource accordingly.

But I am not sure if that would work since the JDBCtemplate is already defined as a spring boot project and I don't know it's scope (I assume if it is not a session bean, changing the DataSource would be for all users, not just for one user)

Does anyone have an idea about how should I tackle this problem? Please let me know!

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve with 2 users? As far as I can tell, it doesn't help with anything. Perhaps you're confusing your user access rights with your application's access rights?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create 2 JdbcTemplate beans:

```
// declare
@Bean("jdbc1")
public JdbcTemplate createJdbcTemplate1(@Autowired @Qualifier("datasource1") DataSource dataSource1){
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource1);
}

@Bean("jdbc2")
public JdbcTemplate createJdbcTemplate2(@Autowired @Qualifier("datasource2") DataSource dataSource2){
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource2);
}
```

and specify name of bean when autowiring:

```
// use jdbcTemplate1 for login/register/information
@Autowired
@Qualifier("jdbc1")
protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1;

// use jdbcTemplate2 for other
@Autowired
@Qualifier("jdbc2")
protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2;
```

Comment: Can you please provide me with the necessary dependencies to use jdbctemplate in spring boot (maven or gradle, doesn't matter)? I've been trying for the past couple of hours to find them and none of the ones I've found works.

Comment: You can add below dependency:
    
    <dependency>  
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>  
    </dependency>

Answer (score -2):

First you should config two data source.
Connect different data sources according to different operations.