# Using two datasources with different jdbc drivers with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I followed the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-two-datasources) and created some sourcecode that is quite identical to the given example. When I run my code I get this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver claims to
>   not accept jdbcUrl,
>   jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

The strange thing is that two things are mixed:

- the h2-jdbcUrl is treated by the mariaDB-driver
- the query that my previously existing code runs it targetted against mariaDB (I have not yet written any code that used the second datasource)

These are my beans:

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("datasources.first")
public DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("datasources.first.configuration")
public HikariDataSource firstDataSource() {
    return firstDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("datasources.second")
public DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("datasources.second.configuration")
public HikariDataSource secondDataSource() {
    return secondDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
}
```

My application.yml looks like this:

```
datasources:
  first:
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:mariadb://...
    username: ...
    password: ...
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
  second:
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:/tmp/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: ...
    password: ...
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

This is the code that causes the exception:

```
@Component
public class Updater {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    Queries queries;

    public List<User> getActiveUsers() throws Exception {
        List<User> users = jdbcTemplate.query(queries.getActive(), new UserRowMapper());

        return users;
    }
```

In order to diagnose this further I enabled the `configprops` and `beans` endpoints and checked their output.
The config looks good and the beans too:

Config (one of many):

```
    "firstDataSourceProperties": {
      "prefix": "datasources.first",
      "properties": {
        "password": "******",
        "initializationMode": "EMBEDDED",
        "driverClassName": "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver",
        "generateUniqueName": false,
        "xa": {
          "properties": {}
        },
        "separator": ";",
        "platform": "all",
        "continueOnError": false,
        "username": "..."
      }
```

Bean (one of many):

```
"firstDataSource": {
          "aliases": [],
          "scope": "singleton",
          "type": "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource",
          "resource": "...Application",
          "dependencies": [
            "firstDataSourceProperties"
          ]
        }
```

I use Spring Boot 2.2.6

Comment: You have to set JdbcTemplate bean with respect to data sources, [Please have look this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171537/use-two-datasources-with-jdbc-template)

Comment: @Az.MaYo Thanks a lot for this pointer, but I still receive `Driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:h2:...` although your comment solved my (future ?) problem with differentiating two JdbcTemplates

Comment: show your datasource properties. it will help to identify problem

Comment: "Just for fun" I made an intentional mistake and forced the use of the second datasource by connecting the wrong JdbcTemplate and had it call an incorrect SQL statement. The error returned is a `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException`, that means the second datasource uses the correct driver

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib You mean those from the application properties or something else ?

Comment: application properties

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib They are in the post already and there are no `spring.datasource` entries at all

Comment: show your full jdbc url without ip and port

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211719/discussion-between-marged-and-golam-mazid-sajib).

Comment: @GolamMazidsajib `jdbc:mariadb://server:3306/foo?useSSL=true&trustServerCertificate=true&serverSslCert=/foo.cer`, this connection string works fine when used with `spring.datasource` and it worked with `datasources.first` before I added all the `@Primary` stuff and the second datasource

Comment: really its strange. you can remove driver class name. let spring to auto detect. 2 datasource working fine at my machine

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by me not understanding the interaction between `DataSourceProperties` and `HikariDataSource`.

I found out that the `jdbcUrl` didn't carry the value I configured, this could be seen by the details of the `firstDataSource`:

```
"firstDataSource": {
  "prefix": "datasources.first.configuration",
  "properties": {
    "initializationFailTimeout": 1,
    "validationTimeout": 5000,
    "readOnly": false,
    "registerMbeans": false,
    "healthCheckProperties": {},
    "isolateInternalQueries": false,
    "leakDetectionThreshold": 0,
    "maxLifetime": 1800000,
    "minimumIdle": 10,
    "metricsTrackerFactory": {},
    "allowPoolSuspension": false,
    "idleTimeout": 600000,
    "dataSourceProperties": {},
    "driverClassName": "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver",
    "jdbcUrl": "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE",
    "loginTimeout": 0,
    "maximumPoolSize": 10,
    "autoCommit": true,
    "connectionTimeout": 30000,
    "username": "...",
    "poolName": "HikariPool-1"
}
```

As you can see the `jdbcUrl` addresses h2. This is caused by the fact that I set "my" intended url at `datasources.first.jdbcUrl`. But after that the (non-existing) value of `datasources.first.configuration.jdbcUrl` was read which was not configured and obviously set to a default.

After I changed my application.yml to this it worked:

```
datasources:
  first:
    username: ...
    password: ...
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    configuration:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mariadb://...
```

I will need to decide which value to put where, the `username` and `password` could be moved one level deeper too, but that's another story ...